# How to show two column of graph in same graph in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am a new iOS developer and I want to show graph as shown in image. Is it possible to show like this graph.If yes please share some code or example.[image]

Comment: Try [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) BarChart (grouped DataSets)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR It is in swift.

Comment: It has Objective-c demo project

Comment: @Mujtaba you can add this third party chart it is grate and easy to understand https://github.com/chasseurmic/TWRCharts

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Do you know how to add value on bar graph top in TWRCharts.